# Tradingview pinescript plotsymbol

Tags: pine-script

is there any way to check whether any Plotshape symbol on top/below the bar using a condition in Tradingview pine script. I have a protected strategy with symbols, thinking of adding a indicator with alertcondition by checking those plotted symbols?

Comment: There is no clear answer, it depends on the implementation of the output in the protected strategy. You should investigate in debugging what output variables are available to you.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion that the protected strategy is having plotsymbols for enter/exit,and tradingview alerts for enter/exit works on same 3commas botid/email token and not separate 3commas message for entry/exit. I am trying for a way to provide bot message for buy and sell separately so that when 'sell' i can give SHORT message as well. any suggestion to achieve this?